# ASP.NET DateTime Column in Database Getting Set to Current Date on Page Load

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to solve an issue where a database column is getting set when navigating to a page in an ASP.NET site. This is a quote management web application, and when opening a quote and navigating to a certain page, the "Expiration Date" is automatically updated to the current date. I have verified that this is occurring prior to triggering the Page_Load function in the ascx.cs file. I have tried to trace what is being run prior to this, but I'm afraid my knowledge of ASP.NET is insufficient, and I don't know exactly where to look. From the pieces I can tell are run prior (for example, the aspx.cs file), I see nothing to indicate any alterations to the record.

When I dig deeper, it seems almost as if the change is taking pace upon leaving the main landing page when editing a quote. If I update the value and travel to any page for the quote except for the main page, it stays the same. And I can travel to the main page, check the record in the database, it stays the same. But it seems like as soon as I navigate from that main page, the Expiration Date will change to the current date. Is there somewhere I can check to see if that's what's happening?

**-- EDIT --**

Maybe a detail list of actions might help...

1. View list of quotes in system
2. Click "Edit" link for quote
3. View "Quote Details" page, which is first page upon edit access
4. Look at database query for quote to see exp date is still proper
   value
5. Click "Quote Options" navigation link
6. See expiration date in "Quote Options" has now changed to current
   date
7. Check database query to see that without performing a known save to
   the database the exp date value has updated in the database
8. Perform update to quote to reset exp date
9. View any other page in quote edit, return to "Options", see exp
   date has not changed again from reset value
10. Verify proper date with database query
11. Revisit "Details" page
12. Again verify correct date with database query
13. Travel to any other page and then to "Options", or go straight
     to "Options", see that exp date has changed to current date

This is the HTML on the link used, which appears to be identical on the other pages...

```
<a class="tabOff" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_linkButtonAddEditShipping" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$linkButtonAddEditShipping", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Quote Options</a>
```

Comment: I guess your problem is when you submit the quote page is getting reloaded and the code is again executed(whole page load section)  try putting the date setup code in if(!isPostBack){}

Comment: That's the thing, nothing is being submitted. You can access the entry page for editing the quote, and then navigate to another page for editing the quote, and the value is changed. However, if you submit the change on that page to put the value back and navigate to any page for the quote without going to the main page, the value does not change. There are no forms submitted to cause the change, and the value is already changed before you can test for *if (!IsPostBack())*

Comment: There's not much anyone can do to help you without seeing an example of the problem.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Sort of. I did discover that the save function was being triggered when leaving the "Details" page, even though no save action was being explicitly activated. The problem was resolved by getting the expiration date from the database at the beginning of the function, and if one was set, pushing that value back in at the very end of the function. While this has in effect prevented the value from being "overwritten", I am still unable to determine why the save function was being triggered, and unable to determine what actions within that function are setting the value to be the current date